# capture two-finger scroll event on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking for a way to implement gestures for zoom, pan and rotate in a 3d app. I'm using a `ScaleGestureDetector` for the zoom events and a `GestureDetector` for the pan. I was hoping to be able to differentiate between a two-finger scroll and a one-finger scroll through the `getPointerCount()` method on the `MotionEvent` that comes in, but any time it sees it as a two-point scroll, the scale detector kicks in. the regular detector never gets passed a motionevent where the pointer count is > 1.

any ideas? is it a matter of setting a span threshold internally and returning `false` from the onScale event when it's below the threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mentioned is one option. You can return false in the onScaleBegin() when it is below the threshold.

Also, there is a GestureDetector [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector%28android.content.Context,%20android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean%29) which takes a boolean ignoreMultiTouch. If you set this to false, it will still attempt to interpret the gestures, even with multiple pointers. I don't know how well it would work out with a scale detector at the same time.

Comment: I know that setting `ignoreMultiTouch` to true helped me a lot, but I was looking for preventing scrolling with two fingers :) So +1 on the answer, even though I did not have the same question.